# .JS file opening blank in browser

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

javascript(.js) file opening blank in the browser, when changing name it's showing all content.
ex - regular-method.js -> opens blank
regular-method1.js - opens with all it's content

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem in my test.

**For example:**

1. I can read Item_Highlight.js

[image]

2. Rename the Item_Highlight.js to Item_Highlight111.js

[image]

3. Open Item_Highlight111.js

[image]

I suggest you can delete and re-upload the .js file. After renaming the .js file,  please clear browser cache and refresh page

Comment: It happened in Sharepoint 2013 not in online, and it did not happened for all files only for one file (regular-method.js) - when opening just like u did showing blank, and when renamed it shows all code written in it.